# Are standard input, output, and error descriptors constants defined in the standard library?

Tags: python

I cannot find these basic constants anywhere in the Python library.

```
STDIN = 0
STDOUT = 1
STDERR = 2
```

It's trivial, but I just can't believe I have to define them myself.

Answer (score 7):

The values can be determined from the `sys` module:

```
sys.stdout.fileno()
sys.stdin.fileno()
sys.stderr.fileno()
```

Comment: In python 3.x it'll raise `AttributeError: 'FakeOutput' object has no attribute 'fileno'`.

Comment: @KevinGuan, I used Python 3.  Are you using an IDE?  It sounds like it has overridden the streams.

Comment: Ah, Because I'm using bpython...never mind about it.

Comment: You are right about the values. But these values are well-known and the main reason to use constants is to make a program more readable. Compare: `os.isatty(2)`,  `os.isatty(STDERR)`,  `os.isatty(sys.stderr.fileno())`. Anyway it seems that I have not overlooked those constants, but they are simply not there for whatever reason. Maybe they are not so frequently used in general as I have assumed.

Comment: This doesn't work if `sys.stdout` or the other streams were changed (for example with `contextlib.redirect_stdout` or by assigning them). It's best not to rely on it. It also might not work for GUI apps.

Answer (score 0):

pty.STDIN_FILENO, pty.STDOUT_FILENO, pty.STDERR_FILENO

Comment: Seems to be an undocumented feature. Those constants are not mentioned in the docs and not included in pty's `__all__`